# What does the author mean with the pseudocode below?

Tags: c++, templates

The following was obtained in page 330 from B.Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" Third Edition :

```
template<class C> struct String<C>::Srep {
  C* s;   // pointer to elements
  int sz; // number of elements
  int n; // reference count
  // ...
};

template<class C> C String<C>::read(int i) const { return rep->s[i];}

template<class C> String<C>::String()
{
  p = new Srep(0, C());
}
```

I have two questions about the above constructor:

1) Shouldn't `p` be replaced by `rep` ?

2) How the ctor `Srep(0, C())` is supposed to construct a `Srep` object in the store ?

Comment: There have been 20+ printings, in my version p is rep.

Comment: @Red Serpent But what about the constructor call `Srep(0, C())`?

Comment: This isn't "pseudocode", it is a generic implementation in _real_ code.

Comment: There were and, probably, will be some typos. See errata for
"The C++ Programming Language (Second edition)", 1991 (http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bs-errata-2.html)

Answer (score 3):

To 1): Yes. In my book I have following code:

```
template<class C> struct String<C>::Srep {
  C* s;   // pointer to elements
  int sz; // number of elements
  int n; // reference count
};

template<class C> C String<C>::read(int i) cont { return rep->s[i];}

template<class C> String<C>::String<C>()
{
  rep = new Srep(0, C());
}
```

Comment: This is the same Edition but german. This code you can find also by google, take a look: http://books.google.de/books?id=3uhuFrKoyL8C&pg=PA352&lpg=PA352&dq=template%3Cclass+C%3E+struct+String%3Cc%3E::Srep&source=bl&ots=49g3PcV52T&sig=ST2hJCcvL1c6GzP3tIXR-wslr4w&hl=de&sa=X&ei=42AqUcCBLMSG4ASz54DQAg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=template%3Cclass%20C%3E%20struct%20String%3Cc%3E%3A%3ASrep&f=false

Comment: @duDE Any comment about my second question ?

Comment: I would mean, this is just a pseudo code that implies, in ctor of String will be crteated a new instance of structure Srep, and nothing else (...) ?